# Trigger de Update em Mysql

Tags: mysql, trigger

Não conheço muito de Mysql e preciso fazer uma trigger para atualizar uma linha logo após sua inserção. Quando o usuário cadastra um pedido ele seleciona quantos pedidos ele deseja. No banco de dados é salvo em uma coluna o tipo e em outra coluna a quantidade que ele solicitou. 
Eu desejo que toda vez que entrar um novo pedido a minha trigger atualize o campo tipo para (quantidade-tipo)
Minha trigger está assim mas nada acontece após inserir novo registro:

```
delimiter $$
create trigger Atualiza_Pedido

after insert on loja.pedido for each row

Begin

if new.method = 'metodo' 

then

update loja.pedido
set tipo = concat(new.quantidade,'-', new.tipo)
where id = new.id;

end if;
END$$
```

Answer (score 0):

Você não precisa fazer o `UPDATE`, basta setar o valor:

```
delimiter $$
create trigger Atualiza_Pedido

before insert on loja.pedido for each row
Begin
    if new.method = 'metodo' then
        set new.tipo = concat(new.quantidade,'-', new.tipo);
    end if;
END$$
```

Na realidade, esta `TRIGGER` tem que ser executada antes de inserir e não depois, por isso troquei o `AFTER` pelo `BEFORE`.

Comment: fiz essas alterações e deu erro dizendo que o campo tipo não estava declarado. Acrescentei então um **declare tipo varchar (30).** Fiz um novo pedido mas o campo não atualizou.

Comment: tire o `declare tipo varchar(30)` e no lugar de `set tipo` coloque `set new.tipo`, vou alterar na resposta também.

Comment: também não funcionou ainda. Tentei _old_ também mas nem permite... é _before insert_ mesmo?